# Filter android adb logs in terminal when using Timber

Tags: android, logging, mobile, adb, timber-android

In my app, I am using [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) as a logger. I am accessing the logs from the terminal via adb using this isntruction:

```
./adb logcat com.company.my_app:D
```

I do get the logs but the issue is that I am getting a crazy amount of noise from the OS (ie `SurfaceFlinger` , `GraphicBuffer`, `vndksupport`) which make the logs harder to read.

Is there a way to filter the logs like in Android Studio and just get logs from my app. Thank you !

P.S. I have trie a few answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android) but none of them remove the noise.

Comment: try to use pidcat https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works best for me is to grep for the process ID which is displayed in every log line. In the example below **7098** is printed with every log line.

```
08-10 18:48:39.825  7098  7144 D NetworkModule: --> END POST
```

So this is the adb instruction used to get filtered logs:

```
adb logcat | grep -F "7098"
```

Note: the process ID is not static and it is going to change if app is hard-closed or device is restarted.

I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works in my case.