# Filtering Logcat Logs android

Tags: android, command-line, adb, logcat

public static final TAG = "Sample:Test";

trying to filter logs only with above tag.

adb logcat Sample:Test:V *:S --> is not returning anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android