# React native app crash without error log ,How to detect a bug?

Tags: android, reactjs, crash, native

I'm developing an android app in react native and it is crash when I install it to my android device, my android device is running on android 10.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "WifiSwitch",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.65.1",
    "react-native-android-wifi": "^0.0.41",
    "react-native-best-viewpager": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-tcp-socket": "^4.5.5",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.17.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to debug your application using **adb logcat**

**Steps to configure**

1. Connect your device to your computer
2. Run `adb devices` to check out if your device is detected.
   *If the command doesn't work because "adb is not a command", go to your **ANDROID_HOME** path, then open `platform-tools`*
3. Now run `adb logcat`: This command will output all logs (debug and error levels) coming from your Android Device.
4. Install your application again. I recommend you to use `react-native run-android`. More info: https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device
5. When your app is going to crash, you will see a Crash Log in the **adb logcat** output. Search for your app package name.
   For your convenience, you could as well have a look here to filter only your app: [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Whenever you get a crash log, a stack trace is also provided. That can help you trace the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much........@Franz Nkemaka

Comment: You're welcome @Rahul. What was your crash log, did you get what caused the bug?