# Android Studio Log Filter AudioManager

Tags: android, android-studio

I never used AudioManager in my code

but This type of Logs are filling my console

How can I stop it ?

```
2021-09-23 07:03:42.392 5686-6405/com.abhi D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume packageName=com.abhi, index=4, streamType=3
2021-09-23 07:03:42.423 5686-6405/com.abhi D/AudioManager: get_do_mute_music = false
2021-09-23 07:03:42.426 5686-6405/com.abhi D/AudioManager: getStreamVolume packageName=com.abhi, index=4, streamType=3
2021-09-23 07:03:42.465 5686-6405/com.abhi D/AudioManager: get_do_mute_music = false
```

**I tried** to add `Edit Filter Configuration`
for package `com.abhi`

but no changes

Comment: You can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android

Comment: @tancolo but this message is from my package `com.abhi`

Answer (score 0):

> but this message is from my package com.abhi

Regards this, I checked the logcat filter in my Android Studio(AS), seems it's a normal case. See the screenshot.

[image: logcat screenshot 1]

Obviously, I didn't use any input, OpenGL, or sth. like that, but in the logcat there are many logs related to them. I can understand it because our App runs on the Android system.

To simply fix your problem, I think you need to use another LOG level to filter the log which is only your log. Or config the filter via `Edit Filter Configuration`
like this:
[image: logcat screenshot 2]

[image: Edit Filter Configuration]

Again, I still suggest you read the answer link I attached before. Because there are many approaches to filter the log, not only As, but also the command of `adb logcat`