# How to debug android apps running in background and Foreground

Tags: android, android-studio, android-background, android-debugging

When we remove an app from foreground logcat gets full of other stuff.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an app running on your device and you want to attach a debugger to its process then you can hit the "Attach Debugger" button as shown in the image below:

[image: Attach Debugger Button]

Then select the process you want to debug. You can only do this with your own apps of course.