# Android Studio emulator shows "Couldn't Launch AR": Google Geospatial API

Tags: android, augmented-reality, geospatial

So I was following this tutorial for creating an AR app : [Geospatial API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/geospatial/codelab#1)

I have followed the exact same steps as shown in the tutorial, but I am getting the following error message: "Couldn't launch AR. To continue, connect to the Internet."

[This is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv4Fc.png)

I have already tried using different android SDKs, but nothing works. I tried using a  different network, but the app started crashing for some reason.
Could someone please help me out! TIA.

P.S. : Internet works fine in the browser and other apps.

Comment: If you are attempting using the emulator, you missed the part on the [first page](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/geospatial/codelab#0): `What you need: A supported ARCore Android device, connected using a USB cable...`

Comment: @MorrisonChang It says on their website that android emulator is supported for AR.

Comment: For Android, screenshots of the 'not working' dialog is less useful than adding the text of relevant [logcat messages](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#running) of the [app that is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6854127/295004) into your question.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Hey so changing API version to 29 worked! It was a pretty random solution, thanks for your responses!