# The screen turns white after entering this fragment. The second time the application stopped working. How to solve this?

Tags: java, android

Given the following code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

context = getActivity();
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shor1, container, false);
NumberPicker1.setDisplayedValues(primeNumbers);
```

I'm just trying to make the fragment open successfully and not display a white screen after entering the fragment. After the white screen, the application stops working.

Comment: Can you please share `adb logcat | grep <<your_aplication_pid>>` ? The crash log would have more information about where the crash is coming from.

Comment: "How to solve this?" First learn how to use the logcat output - follow advice given or if using Android Studio use the `Logcat` window.  Well worth the small initial investment in time.  Here's a [primer](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat)

Answer (score 0):

To know exact reason please start with `adb logcat` output,

```
adb logcat | grep -F "`adb shell ps | grep com.asanayoga.asanarebel  | tr -s [:space:] ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2`"
```

Note that `com.asanayoga.asanarebel` is your package name what you have provided in AndroidManifest.xml.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9869609/6680585

Search for `AndroidRuntime`, it would show the stack trace from where the crash is coming from. This would help you debug quickly.

---

If the above logs didn't help, the following are the potential areas where I would look into,

**Context Handling**: You are assigning context = getActivity(); which is fine, but if you're using this context to do something that requires a valid, non-null context, and the fragment isn't attached to an activity yet, this could cause issues.

**Inflating the Layout**: The line view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shor1, container, false); seems correct, but ensure that R.layout.fragment_shor1 is the correct layout file and that it's properly structured. An improperly structured layout or a typo in the layout name can cause crashes.

**NumberPicker Initialization**: You mentioned NumberPicker1.setDisplayedValues(primeNumbers);, but it's not clear if NumberPicker1 is properly initialized before this line. If NumberPicker1 is null or not properly initialized, trying to call setDisplayedValues on it will cause a NullPointerException.

**Missing primeNumbers Initialization**: If primeNumbers is not initialized or is null when you try to set it to the NumberPicker, this could also cause issues.

**Missing Override of onCreateView**: Ensure that @Override is correctly used, and that this method is properly overriding the onCreateView method from the Fragment class.

**Error Handling**: There might be exceptions thrown that are not caught, leading to the application crashing. Implementing proper error handling could provide more insight into what's going wrong.

Comment: Ah that's for catching that. Updated the answer.

Comment: I just used the same example from another SO answer for `adb logcat`. But it's always better to call it out explicitly that the value has to be replaced. Thanks @Computable. Really appreciate the input.

Comment: i'm not sure on the value of this answer. you're suggesting to OP where they should go debug, which is a lengthly list of things to consider. is this 1. question going to be useful to others in future ? then, 2,  is this answer going to be useful to others in future ? is this question [enough](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to recreate the problem for us, here ? why isn't this just a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: This answer is a guideline on how they could start with troubleshooting. OP could comment on what went wrong. 1. Yes, when OP updated 'AndroidRuntime' stacktrace in the question, followed by updating my answer with the thing that went wrong exactly 2. Not at the moment. It will be when OP included exactly what's there within their 'onCreateView' with minimal code to reproduce the bug.